# Setup https and www redirect on Rails Passenger and a WordPress installation on Apache on Amazon Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, passenger

I want http://www.example.com, http://example.com to redirect to https://example.com.

The application hosted at https://example.com is a Rails Passenger app.

I have a WordPress installation in `/var/www/html/blog` and I've aliased `/blog` to `/var/www/html/blog` such that https://example.com/blog will run the WordPress blog.

However, not everything is working as I want:

Right now:

1. http://www.example.com is going to https://example.com, this is good.
2. http://example.com is not going to https://example.com.
3. https://www.example.com is not going to https://example.com
4. https://example.com/blog is throwing exceptions in the console like this: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/blog/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/blog/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.6.1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
   e @ (index):23`
5. http://example.com/blog runs fine, but I need it to redirect to https://example.com/blog **
6. http://www.example.com/blog redirects to http://example.com/blog **

** Points 5 and 6, this is probably because I have set the WordPress urls to http://example.com. If I set it to https://example.com, I get into an endless loop.

Can I get advice on how to modify my apache config?

`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/passenger-5.1.0/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
 PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/passenger-5.1.0
 PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/wrappers/ruby
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    # Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public
    # Redirect / https://example.com

    PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/wrappers/ruby
    PassengerFriendlyErrorpages on

    # JkMount /tc* node1
    # JkMount /intro* node1

    # Relax Apache security settings
    <Directory /var/www/example/public>
        RailsEnv production
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
        # Require all granted

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] OR
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/blog>
        PassengerEnabled off
        # Makes Wordpress's .htaccess file work
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Alias /blog /var/www/html/blog
Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ /var/www/example/.well-known/acme-challenge/
`
```

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Listen 443

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLMutex default

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn

SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"

<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

# to run in dev mode
RailsEnv production

# Be sure to point to 'public'!
DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public

# define server details
ServerName example.com
#ServerAlias www.example.com

# rails needs the header for its own processing
RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'

# this is just passing a proxy to a localhost server
# ProxyRequests Off
# ProxyPreserveHost On
# <Proxy *>
# Order deny,allow
# Allow from all
# </Proxy>
# ProxyPass / http://localhost/
# ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/

#<Directory /var/www/html/blog>
#  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
#  AllowOverride All
#  allow from all
#  Require all granted
#</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You should setup your [wordpress blog properly](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/)  so that it uses HTTPs. I would still take Radiant or Refinery over the pile of junk that is WP any day.

Comment: I think because I had to reverse proxy and also wanted /blog to point to the WordPress installation, it wasn't as straight forward. WordPress offers custom themes and plugins that are not readily available in these less-known engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following to work for redirecting everything to `https://example.com`, but I could not get https to work for /blog:

`httpd.conf`

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/passenger-5.1.0/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
 PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/passenger-5.1.0
 PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/wrappers/ruby
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    # Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public

    PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/wrappers/ruby
    PassengerFriendlyErrorpages on

    # Relax Apache security settings
    <Directory /var/www/example/public>
        RailsEnv production
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
        # Require all granted

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.adintern.com
        RewriteRule  ^(.*)$        https://adintern.com/$1 [L,R=301]

        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*)           https://adintern.com/$1

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/blog>
        PassengerEnabled off
        # Makes Wordpress's .htaccess file work
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Alias /blog /var/www/html/blog
Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ /var/www/example/.well-known/acme-challenge/
```

`ssl.conf`

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Listen 443

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLMutex default

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn

SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"

<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

# to run in dev mode
RailsEnv production

# Be sure to point to 'public'!
DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public

# define server details
ServerName example.com

# rails needs the header for its own processing
RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'

# this is just passing a proxy to a localhost server
# ProxyRequests Off
# ProxyPreserveHost On
# <Proxy *>
# Order deny,allow
# Allow from all
# </Proxy>
# ProxyPass / http://localhost/
# ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/

SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/chain.pem

</VirtualHost>
```

For WordPress, set the `HOME` and `SITEURL` to this:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com/blog');
```